# java group stream elements by unrelated set of elements

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

Now this is the Problem, I want to group a stream of elements by another unrelated element with comparable attributes.

I have a Species class consisting of a temperature range(int lower, upper)
and a Planet class consisting of a name and a constant temperature(String name; int temp).

```
public class Species{
  int lower, upper;

  constructor....
  getter....
}

public class Planet{
  String name;
  int temp;

  contructor....
  getter....
}
```

How would I go about grouping my Stream of Planet by the Species which can live on them (when the planet temperature lies inside the temperature range of a species) resulting in a :

`Map <Planet, Set<Species>>`

Here for example is a stream of planets I want to group:

```
Set<Species> speciesSet = Stream.of(new Species(5, 70), new Species(100, 220), new Species(75, 80)).collect(Collectors.toSet());

Stream.of(new Planet("blue planet", 45), new Planet("red planet", 150), new Planet("green planet", 77)).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(       , Collectors.toSet()));
```

My first Idea about what I should group by was something like this- `plnt -> first element from speciesSet.stream() filtered by plnt.getTemp`

but that looks highly inefficient and also would be problematic if there is actually no Species that fits the planet temperature to return as first element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact all you're looking for is a lookup that could map a planet to a collection of compatible Species. And that's fairly easy to get to if you use a "mapping" class such as the following (and this is only needed because Java doesn't have any kind of type-aware, Tuple-like data structure):

```
public static class PlanetSpecies {
    Planet planet;
    Set<Species> species;

    public PlanetSpecies(Planet planet, Set<Species> species) {
        this.planet = planet;
        this.species = species;
    }

    public Planet getPlanet() {
        return planet;
    }

    public Set<Species> getSpecies() {
        return species;
    }
}
```

Using that, you can easily construct a collection of `PlanetSpecies` from your two collections in this way:

```
Set<PlanetSpecies> planetSpecies = Stream
        .of(new Planet("blue planet", 45), 
            new Planet("red planet", 150), 
            new Planet("green planet", 77))
        .map(speciesMapper)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

That results in the following output, which is basically your original list of planets mapped to a set of its compatible species:

```
[ {
  "planet" : {
    "name" : "blue planet",
    "temp" : 45
  },
  "species" : [ {
    "lower" : 5,
    "upper" : 70
  } ]
}, {
  "planet" : {
    "name" : "green planet",
    "temp" : 77
  },
  "species" : [ {
    "lower" : 75,
    "upper" : 80
  } ]
}, {
  "planet" : {
    "name" : "red planet",
    "temp" : 150
  },
  "species" : [ {
    "lower" : 100,
    "upper" : 220
  } ]
} ]
```

That in a sense means you don't need to "group".

However, if you need the result to be like a `Map<planet_name, Set<Species>>`, then a little more needs to be done:

```
Map<String, Set<Species>> planetSpecies = Stream
        .of(new Planet("blue planet", 45), 
            new Planet("red planet", 150), 
            new Planet("green planet", 77))
        .map(speciesMapper)
        .collect(
            Collectors.groupingBy(
                (PlanetSpecies sp) -> sp.getPlanet().getName(),
                Collectors.mapping(species -> species.getSpecies(), 
                        Collectors.reducing(new HashSet<Species>(), speciesReducer)
                        )
                ));
```

With the reducer being declared as:

```
BinaryOperator<Set<Species>> speciesReducer = (set1, set2) -> {
    Set<Species> newSet = new HashSet<>();

    newSet.addAll(set1);
    newSet.addAll(set2);

    return newSet;
};
```

This reducer is basically doing a `set.union`.

The above results in the following output:

```
{
  "green planet" : [ {
    "lower" : 75,
    "upper" : 80
  } ],
  "blue planet" : [ {
    "lower" : 5,
    "upper" : 70
  } ],
  "red planet" : [ {
    "lower" : 100,
    "upper" : 220
  } ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For each planet, you find which species are able to live, then group them by your planet:

```
Stream.of(..planets...)
      .flatMap(p -> speciesSet.stream().filter(s -> s.lower <= p.temp && p.temp <= s.upper).map(s -> new SimpleEntry<>(p, s)))
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toSet())));
```

Incase your planets are already unique, you don't even need `groupingBy`:

```
Map<Planet, Set<Species>> result = new HashMap<>();
Stream.of(..planets...)
      .forEach(p -> result.put(p, 
                          peciesSet.stream()
                              .filter(s -> s.lower <= p.temp && p.temp <= s.upper)
                              .collect(Collectors.toSet()))
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I would create this method to simply the code and improve readability:

```
class Planet {
    boolean canSupport(Species species) {
        return temp >= species.getLower() && temp <= species.getUpper();
    }
}
```

It also lets you easily add more conditions later, like atmospheric requirements and local star requirements.

Then, do this:

```
import static // various classes
Map<Planet, Set<Species>> map = Stream.of(...) // Stream of Planets
    .distinct() // use this if stream has duplicate Plansts (unlikely)
    .map(p -> new SimpleEntry(p, speciesSet.stream().filter(p::canSupport).collect(toSet()))) // collect species for planet
    .filter(e -> !e.getValue().isEmpty()) // ignore planets supporting no species
    .collect(toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

The resulting map will only contain planets that can support at least 1 species, but only calculate the species list once.

—-

To improve efficiency of finding species, put them in two `TreeMap<Integer, Set<Species>>`s, one for upper and one for lower temperature, then use `NavigableMap`s methods (left to reader) to find supportable species in O(k) (where k is the number of supportable species) instead of O(n) (the number of all species).